# YII - fetch a record if found on creation page

Tags: ajax, yii

Am new to YII framework. I want to know how to fetch the customer information with the phonenumber entered while creating a new customer using ajax with out submitting the form.

If i found any customer with entered telephone then we need to alert the user with confirmation to proceed with creation or entering new customer.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use unique validator for you customers AR class

```
class Customers extends CActiveRecord
{
.....................
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
.........................
            array('phone', 'unique'),
.........................
        );
    }

.........................


}
```

And enable ajaxValidation in your form

Comment: Just to add, you will need to normalize the input before the unique validator fires